# Nested lapply to modify tables instead of loops

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I'm still trying to understand functions in R such as apply, lapply etc. As far as I know loops in R are slow and it's good practice to avoid them. However making 'one-line-scripts' which do everything is pretty dificult. Nevertheless I's like to forget about loops and switch to bulit-in fast functions.
My input data - two tables:

**L1**

```
N   Q   string
1   12  NNN|ABC|12.5
2   46  DEF|111|!-2
3   34  $$%GHI|--+
4   -2  345H*(JKL
5   50  NK-|224ABC
6   0   NNNNNNNNN
```

and **L2**

```
str
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PRS
```

What I Want to get:

```
N   Q   string          sub
1   12  NNN|ABC|12.5    ABC
2   46  DEF|111|!-2     DEF
3   34  $$%GHI|--+    GHI
4   -2  345H*(JKL       JKL
5   50  NK-|224ABC      ABC
6   0   NNNNNNNNN       NA
```

As you see specific substring is extracted from string(very random, without any template inside) and added at the end of each row respectively.

I made a short script in R with loops which allows to do this, nevertheless in my non-fake data table L1 has over 80000 rows and table L2 up to 250000 rows, so this simple operation may take i bit of time.

```
L1 <- cbind(sub=NA,L1)
L1 <- subset(L1, select=c(N:string,sub))
for(i in 1:nrow(L2)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(L1)){
    if(grepl(L2[i,1], L1[j,3])){
      L1$sub[j] <- toString(L2$str[i])
    }
  }
}
```

I was thinking about nested lapply, but how can I get to the specific index?
Ultra pseudocode:

```
lapply(L1, function(x) lapply(L2, function(y) if(L2 in L1) add L2 to L1 else add NA))
```

Beer and huge thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
L1$sub <- str_extract(L1$string, paste(L2$str, collapse="|"))
L1$sub
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "JKL" "ABC" NA
```

Comment: If you want to account for the possibility that a string in L1 may match more than one pattern in L2  (e.g. `L1$string[1] <- "NNN|ABC|DEF|12.5"`) you could use `str_extract_all`: `L1$sub <- stringr::str_extract_all(L1$string, paste(L2$str, collapse="|")) %>% lapply(paste, collapse = ",") %>% unlist %>% replace(., . == "", NA)`.

Comment: Ahh, pretty amazing :D

Comment: I'd like only to add one thing. After small modifications of my solution and given solution above, I run both scripts on my data and I measured time difference: My solution: **Time difference of 48.31354 mins** Given solution: **Time difference of 30.6875 secs**. One more time, very thanks!